# How do I install Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlParser?

Tags: c#, dll, sql-server-2012, sql-parser

My c# installer project came up with a load of warnings when I rebuilt it on a new machine. The warnings were of the ilk that they were looking for version 11.0.0.0 of a dll where only version 10.0.0.0 existed. This I found was due to the version of SQL Server installed (SQL Server 2008 R2). Most of the dll's were specifically due to the version of the Share Management Objects package not being version 11.0.0.0.

So I installed SqlSysClrTypes.msi (x86) that is required for Shared Management Objects. I then installed ShareManagementObjects.msi (x86). I got them from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=29065).

Some of the errors have gone, but now I get 2 that seem to reference the same dll that should have been installed from SharedManagementObjects.msi. It must be obtainable / installed with something as I currently have version 10.0.0.0.

The errors are:

> Unable to find dependency 'MICROSOFT.SQLSERVER.MANAGEMENT.SQLPARSER'
>   (Signature='89845DCD8080CC91' Version='11.0.0.0') of assembly
>   'Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll'

and:

> Unable to find dependency 'MICROSOFT.SQLSERVER.MANAGEMENT.SQLPARSER'
>   (Signature='89845DCD8080CC91' Version='11.0.0.0') of assembly
>   'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SmoMetadataProvider.dll'

Everything I've read suggests that Microsoft.sqlserver.management.sqlparser should have been installed as part of SharedManagementObjects.msi. Is there something I can do to get this dll? Is there something else I need to install such as the Native Client?

Comment: Have you found anything with this?  I can find it in the GAC (by physically looking) put I don't see it in Visual Studio C# references.

Comment: @MikeJansen - I got the dll from a friend in the end. I suspect it's part of the native client download or something similar. If you've got it in the GAC then it surely must have been on your machine at some point. Have you searched for it?

Comment: I just ended up pointing directly to c:\windows\assemblies\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlParser.dll by browsing and it's working.  Just odd that it didn't come up in References anywhere.

Comment: the dll is located under c:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL

Answer (score 3):

I solved the same problem by installing the file ENU\x64\TSqlLanguageService.msi. You can find it here:

[Select here the file TSqlLanguageService.msi](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=52676)