# Unable to find dependency 'MICROSOFT.SQLSERVER.MANAGEMENT.SQLPARSER'

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, setup-project, sql-parser

I am trying to deploy a winforms app and it won't start when I run the Setup file. I have checked the log during the build of the setup project and it says that I need version 11 of:

> MICROSOFT.SQLSERVER.MANAGEMENT.SQLPARSER

I am currently running VS2017 and SQL Server Management Studio and SQL Express version 14. I have the Parser in version 13 and 14, but I still get the same issue as because for some reason it is looking for version 11, which I cannot install.

I have spent two days trying to fix and can't. I have installed various feature packs where possible, but I am totally stuck.

Build output:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: CSV Manager, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(3867,5): warning MSB3177: Reference 'Microsoft.SqlServer.ServiceBrokerEnum' does not allow partially trusted callers.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(3867,5): warning MSB3177: Reference 'Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlEnum' does not allow partially trusted callers.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(3867,5): warning MSB3177: Reference 'Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo' does not allow partially trusted callers.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(3867,5): warning MSB3177: Reference 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc' does not allow partially trusted callers.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(3867,5): warning MSB3177: Reference 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo' does not allow partially trusted callers.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(3867,5): warning MSB3177: Reference 'System.Diagnostics.EventLog' does not allow partially trusted callers.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(3867,5): warning MSB3177: Reference 'System.Security.AccessControl' does not allow partially trusted callers.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(3867,5): warning MSB3177: Reference 'System.Security.Permissions' does not allow partially trusted callers.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(3867,5): warning MSB3177: Reference 'System.Security.Principal.Windows' does not allow partially trusted callers.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(3867,5): warning MSB3177: Reference 'System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController' does not allow partially trusted callers.
1>  CSV Manager -> C:\Users\D\Dropbox\VS Project\CSVGenerator\CSV Manager\CSV Manager\bin\Debug\CSV Manager.exe
------ Starting pre-build validation for project 'Mappi CSV Manager' ------ 
------ Starting pre-build validation for project 'Mappi CSV Manager' ------ 
WARNING: Unable to find dependency 'MICROSOFT.SQLSERVER.MANAGEMENT.SQLPARSER' (Signature='89845DCD8080CC91' Version='11.0.0.0') of assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll'
WARNING: Unable to find dependency 'MICROSOFT.SQLSERVER.MANAGEMENT.SQLPARSER' (Signature='89845DCD8080CC91' Version='11.0.0.0') of assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll'
WARNING: Unable to find dependency 'MICROSOFT.SQLSERVER.MANAGEMENT.SQLPARSER' (Signature='89845DCD8080CC91' Version='11.0.0.0') of assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SmoMetadataProvider.dll'
WARNING: Unable to find dependency 'MICROSOFT.SQLSERVER.MANAGEMENT.SQLPARSER' (Signature='89845DCD8080CC91' Version='11.0.0.0') of assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SmoMetadataProvider.dll'
------ Pre-build validation for project 'Mappi CSV Manager' completed ------
------ Pre-build validation for project 'Mappi CSV Manager' completed ------
2>------ Build started: Project: Mappi CSV Manager, Configuration: Debug ------
2>------ Build started: Project: Mappi CSV Manager, Configuration: Debug ------
Building file 'C:\Users\D\Dropbox\VS Project\CSVGenerator\CSV Manager\Mappi CSV Manager\Debug\Mappi CSV Manager.msi'...
Building file 'C:\Users\D\Dropbox\VS Project\CSVGenerator\CSV Manager\Mappi CSV Manager\Debug\Mappi CSV Manager.msi'...
Packaging file 'Microsoft.SqlServer.ServiceBrokerEnum.dll'...
Packaging file 'Microsoft.SqlServer.ServiceBrokerEnum.dll'...
Packaging file 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll'...
Packaging file 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll'...
Packaging file 'CSV Manager.exe'...
Packaging file 'CSV Manager.exe'...
Packaging file 'dbScript.sql'...
Packaging file 'dbScript.sql'...
Packaging file 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Diagnostics.STrace.dll'...
Packaging file 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Diagnostics.STrace.dll'...
Packaging file 'AnalysisServicesProject.ico'...
Packaging file 'AnalysisServicesProject.ico'...
Packaging file 'CSV Manager.exe.config'...
Packaging file 'CSV Manager.exe.config'...
Packaging file 'System.Security.AccessControl.dll'...
Packaging file 'System.Security.AccessControl.dll'...
Packaging file 'System.Security.Permissions.dll'...
Packaging file 'System.Security.Permissions.dll'...
Packaging file 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.dll'...
Packaging file 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.dll'...
Packaging file 'System.Security.Principal.Windows.dll'...
Packaging file 'System.Security.Principal.Windows.dll'...
Packaging file 'Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo.dll'...
Packaging file 'Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo.dll'...
Packaging file 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SmoMetadataProvider.dll'...
Packaging file 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SmoMetadataProvider.dll'...
Packaging file 'System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController.dll'...
Packaging file 'System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController.dll'...
Packaging file 'System.Diagnostics.EventLog.dll'...
Packaging file 'System.Diagnostics.EventLog.dll'...
Packaging file 'Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlEnum.dll'...
Packaging file 'Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlEnum.dll'...
Packaging file 'Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlClrProvider.dll'...
Packaging file 'Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlClrProvider.dll'...
Packaging file 'System.Net.Http.dll'...
Packaging file 'System.Net.Http.dll'...
Packaging file 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Dmf.dll'...
Packaging file 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Dmf.dll'...
```

Comment: What is CSV Manager on DropBox?

Comment: That is the route to the project. It's stored on Dropbox.

Comment: Have you tried to debug outside DropBox, I had lot of problems in the past with project debugged on OneDrive for me...

Comment: I tried that. It's looking for version 11 of the parser and I can't find it on my machine or on the net.

Comment: I have looked everywhere for a solution, short of rewriting the whole thing from scratch...

Comment: It seems this dll comes with  SSMS Client Tools. On my pc it here "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio". Maybe you can try to reinstall SSMS...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29843703/how-do-i-install-microsoft-sqlserver-management-sqlparser

Comment: Hi All, I have tried your suggestions, I have restarted the App and copied the code over and it seems to be working now...

Comment: Although the issue was resolved by creating a new project, the issue seemed to be two NuGet packages I tried using. One was CSV Helper and the other was LinqtoCSV. I have tried to find the dependencies for these but they don't appear to have any, so I am further stumped. Not having those has prevented further issues as I hardcoded my CSV creator, but I cannot conclusively say if these two were responsible. Obviously not having version 11 of the parser didn't help, but I wonder if that would have papered over a crack I had caused somewhere...